# Need help comparing times using datetime

Tags: php, datetime

I am new to DateTime and I am trying to compare 2 times to see which on is greater. 
In my code below I am trying to see if 1:00am is greater than 12:00am. But for some reason it is outputting false. Can anyone please help me understand why this is happening?? Thanks in advance!

```
$date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"));
$set_time = $date->setTime(00, 00, 00);
echo $date->format('g:i a');

echo "<br>";
$store_closed = "1:00:00";
echo  $store_closed > $set_time  ? 'yes' :  'no';
```

Comment: What's wrong with `$date->diff()`?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am not trying to find the difference between 2 values. I am trying to get a true of false value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work because you compare a DateTime object with a string. You need to use two DateTime objects:

```
$store_closed = DateTime::createFromFormat ('H:i:s', '1:00:00');
echo  ($store_closed > $set_time)  ? 'yes' :  'no';
```